# is there a tool that edits /etc/login.defs for you?

Tags: password

I am attempting to set password expirations for all new accounts and am curious if any tool already exists that will edit /etc/login.defs for you -- or is manually editing the only way?

Comment: I assume this is Linux-specific? And by 'new' do you mean setting the default for future accounts as they are created, or existing ones (as well?)?

Comment: new accounts as they are created.